# add fields to comments programmatically

Tags: 7, entities, comments

I know how add fields to entity, now what is XXX in below code when I want add this field to comment of articles?

```
$instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_image',
    'entity_type' => 'xxx',
    'bundle' => 'xxx',
    'label' => t('Images'),
    ....
```

if any other setting is required, then what is that?

Comment: Comments are not entities and as such can't have attached fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my answer, see:

```
dsm(entity_get_info());
dsm(field_info_bundles());
```

so my code should be:

```
$instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_image',
    'entity_type' => 'comment',
    'bundle' => 'comment_node_article',
    'label' => t('Images'),
    ....
```